# Getting HTTP Status 400 error while running a Servlet class using Tomcat server

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am totally new to writing servlets.  I have created a simple HelloWorld program, but while running the application I'm getting the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/HelloWorld
>
> type Status report
>
> message /HelloWorld/HelloWorld
>
> description: The requested resource is not available.

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;           
    
    public HelloWorld() {
        super();  
    }    
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And my web.xml

```
<display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I'm using Tomcat version:7.0 and my IDE is Eclipse Luna.  Why is this error being thrown?

Comment: show your web.xml file....

Comment: <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
</web-app>

Comment: what is the root directory of your web app?

Comment: @PaulNgom My Project Structure is like this :-                                      Java Resources>src>com.serv>HelloWorld.java                                              WebContent>WEB-INF>web.xml

Comment: remove the first HelloWorld in your url and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @PaulNgom No, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: where is the start web-app tag in web.xml?

Comment: @PaulNgom oops, sorry... I forgot to mention it... well its like this...               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

Comment: remove the annotation in HelloWorld.java and declare it in your web.xml

Comment: @PaulNgom I tried doing that. But I got this error :-                        HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.serv.HelloWorld

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class com.serv.HelloWorld

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: I removed the annotation and added the following code in web.xml  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.serv.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

your_war_file_name/HelloWorld... You can find the war file name under webapps folder in Tomcat directory.  Here I just recreated the same. My war file name is website.war. It works for me. The url is http://localhost:8090/website/developer  . I got the response "Hello World"  .... :)

```
package com.test.developer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Test extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public Test() {
        super();

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside servelt");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and my web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>website</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>developer</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.test.developer.Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>developer</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/developer</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any differnce

Comment: @novel P, per PaulNgom comment, whatever you did is correct. But this time you didnt get 404 error which means your servlet is found by conatiner, your url is correct and since you got the 500 error, there is some other issue. Can you share  the complete stack trace

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.serv.HelloWorld
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)

Comment: org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.serv.HelloWorld
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)

Comment: org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Thanks @novelP .ok.... I have replicated the same and placed my code in Answer section. Can you check. It works for me.

Comment: It seems you java file is not compiled properly. Please check your classes folder, whether HelloWorld java file compiled and created class file there

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't find any 'Classes' folder in my app. Let me tell you how I created my project. I am using Eclipse Luna. New>Dynamic Web Project> HelloWorld. Right click on the project>new>servlet. But I didn't find any 'classes' folder in my app.

Comment: If you open your war file, you can find WEB-INF folder-->classes-->package-->HelloWolrd.class..  Can you check this...

Comment: I tried the same application in other system. It is working fine but in my system it is not generating .class file. What could be the cause?

Comment: Oh!! Thats a good news!! ok...Sometimes It happens with eclipse. Go to menu Project--> Clean--> Clean all the projects. or restart the eclipse. After that, try building the war again and check for class file. All the best!!  If my comments were useful to you, please mark upvote..Thanks

Comment: I cleaned the project. It is working fine. Thanks a lot.